# Нумерация мест в кинотеатре

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Нашел в сети код для бронирования мест в кинозале. 
В нем ошибка - ряд определяется неправильно при бронировании и равняется номеру места. В js не силен, не могу подправить. 
Еще нужно, чтобы данные из div.result попадали в какой-нибудь input.

Буду благодарен за помощь. Ниже код

```js
// план зала по рядам общая вместительность 300 мест
// планов может быть и больше... и разные...
var cinemaHall1 = {
    row: [5, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
  },
  cinemaHallMap = '';
$.each(cinemaHall1.row, function(row, numberOfSeats) {
  cinemaHallRow = '';
  for (i = 1; i <= numberOfSeats; i++) {
    // собираем ряды
    cinemaHallRow += '<div class="seat" data-row="' +
      i + '" data-seat="' +
      i + '">'+i+'</div>';
  }
  //собираем зал с проходами между рядами
  cinemaHallMap += cinemaHallRow + '<div class="passageBetween">&nbsp;</div>';
});

//заполняем в html зал номер 1
$('.zal1').html(cinemaHallMap);
// тут по клику определяем что место выкуплено
$('.seat').on('click', function(e) {
  // если первый раз кликнули билет выкупили, 
  // если повторно значит вернули билет
  $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('bay');
  //показываем сколько билетов выкуплено
  showBaySeat();
});

function showBaySeat() {
  result = '';
  //ищем все места купленные и показываем список выкупленных мест
  $.each($('.seat.bay'), function(key, item) {
    result += '<div class="ticket">Ряд: ' +
      $(item).data().row + ' Место:' +
      $(item).data().seat + '</div>';
  });

  $('.result').html(result);
}
```

```css
.cinemaHall {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.seat {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.passageBetween {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.bay {
  background-color: red;
}
.result {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='result'>
  </div>
  <div class='cinemaHall zal1'></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно немного изменить перебор, сохраняя порядковый номер обработанного места.
Я оставил в коде комментарии, чтобы стало ясно, изменилось.

```js
// план зала по рядам общая вместительность 300 мест
// планов может быть и больше... и разные...
var cinemaHall1 = {
  row: [5, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
};
var cinemaHallMap = '';
// перебираем все ряды
for (var i = 0; i < cinemaHall1.row.length; i++) {
  // запомнили номер ряда
  var rowNumber = i + 1;
  // сколько мест в этом ряду
  var numberOfSeats = cinemaHall1.row[i];
  var cinemaHallRow = '';
  // перебираем места в ряду
  for (var j = 0; j < numberOfSeats; j++) {
    // запомнили номер текущего места
    var seatNumber = j + 1;
    cinemaHallRow += '<div class="seat" data-row="' +
      rowNumber + '" data-seat="' +
      seatNumber + '">' + seatNumber + '</div>';
  }
  cinemaHallMap += cinemaHallRow + '<div class="passageBetween">&nbsp;</div>';
}

//заполняем в html зал номер 1
$('.zal1').html(cinemaHallMap);
// тут по клику определяем что место выкуплено
$('.seat').on('click', function(e) {
  // если первый раз кликнули билет выкупили, 
  // если повторно значит вернули билет
  $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('bay');
  //показываем сколько билетов выкуплено
  showBaySeat();
});

function showBaySeat() {
  result = '';
  //ищем все места купленные и показываем список выкупленных мест
  $.each($('.seat.bay'), function(key, item) {
    result += '<div class="ticket">Ряд: ' +
      $(item).data().row + ' Место:' +
      $(item).data().seat + '</div>';
  });

  $('.result').html(result);
}
```

```css
.cinemaHall {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.seat {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.passageBetween {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.bay {
  background-color: red;
}

.result {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='result'>
  </div>
  <div class='cinemaHall zal1'></div>

</body>
```